# Negotiating with Salesforce.com

Tags: licenses, purchasing

I recently purchased some additional licenses and had to negotiate terms with my rep. I was wondering if anyone had any information to make this go smoother.

The standard terms they are looking for are 12 months, paid upfront. However, you can negotiate that to quarterly, or even monthly. I know some of our customers are paying them far less than the listed price but they have a very high quantity of licenses (thousands). Reps are willing to make more concessions if you will sign a longer agreement.

I've talked to some people that say they are paying monthly and have a small number of group licenses but have been unable to get my rep to do better than quarterly with the deal size we have.

What are the tips/tricks/thresholds to getting a better deal out of Salesforce? Does it just come down to if your rep likes you enough to cut you a deal? Are there scenarios that, if you fit them, should always allow you to get something better?

This question may not be appropriate but I was pretty curious about it and thought I'd throw it out here to see what others thought. It might also be good to make this community wiki if it isn't closed.

**Important Edit**: Just thought about this afterwards - is it a violation of any agreements with SFDC to discuss this openly? I know I don't read those documents very closely - don't want to get anyone in trouble.

Comment: I have no idea if this is a violation of your agreement with SFDC. It is an very good question question, and worthy of discussion, but perhaps this isn't the best forum for it. If you read the FAQ page (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq), you'd have to say that this question is getting away from the focus of the Salesforce stack exchange and probably fits better in the "what kind of questions should I not ask here". Just to be clear, I work for SFDC, but I want to make it clear my job has nothing to do with this question. I'm an instructor.